# How to send & receive RCS (Rich Communication Services) Messages from Android app?

Tags: android, sms, rich-communications-services

Google is promoting and using [RCS](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/13508703) in its [messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging).
As a consequence, it would be good (mandatory ?) for third party SMS apps to support RCS.

I have developed an SMS app in which I sometimes 'encounter' RCS messages.
My app cannot receive RCS messages, but sometimes, a previous app did receive some of these (eg: Google Message App), so my app 'find' these 'old RCS messages in Android SMS DB.

My app is able to read these (at least basic) old messages, but **I have no clue on how to respond to these messages**.

My app is based on [android-smsmms library](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms) and I found some information (2020) about this RCS issue:

> To summarize:
>
> - Third party apps cannot support RCS at this time.
> - Until Google provides APIs or builds RCS support into Android, third party apps will not be able to use it.
> - You can simply disable RCS (or "Advanced Messaging")

src: https://web.archive.org/web/20201111221326/https://github.com/maplemedia/pulse-sms-issues/issues/143

Searching for an RCS library, I found nothing but an old unmaintained library [rcsjta](https://github.com/android-rcs/rcsjta)

---

**Questions:**

- Is RCS open to third party app as of now? Or will soon be? (It was not in 2021: see https://www.xda-developers.com/google-messages-rcs-api-third-party-apps/ )
- Where can I find accurate information about RCS API current status and roadmap?

**Notes:**
Here are some SO questions I've already looked at regarding this:

- [How to read RCS messages from android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736274/how-to-read-rcs-messages-from-android-device-programmatically)
- [How does SMS work (with Android devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128972/how-does-sms-work-with-android-devices)
- [Android: How to incorporate Rich communication Services in Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031277/android-how-to-incorporate-rich-communication-services-in-application)

Comment: Rcs is not a private API, but it is *super* complex. I am unaware of any open source implementation. Google doesn't offer an API to make it easy.

Comment: @MooingDuck you are right, my app can not receive RCS messages. It can read previously received RCS messages form SMS DB, but not receive them.
I updated my question accordingly. Thanks for this precision :-)

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/master/testapps/TestRcsApp/ Apparently Android released an open source app to use as a baseline.

Comment: Any luck finding a way to listen or send RCS messages in Android?

Comment: Still nothing on my side :/